# How do I rewrite the variance in this simplified form?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance

The variance is $$\sigma_y^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2$$ and I am told that we can write it as $$\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{I=1}^ny_i^2-n\bar{y}^2\right)$$

**My attempt**

$$\sigma_y^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^2+\bar{y}^2-2y_i\bar{y})\right) = \frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2+n\bar{y}^2-2\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\right)$$

How do I continue??

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=n\bar y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You are almost done ... Note, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i=n\bar{y}.$$

Comment: oh that was so stupid

Comment: thank you!! I really didn't see it somehow

Comment: That happens from time to time :).